# Follow/Watch a particular question?

Tags: support

Is there a way to watch a particular question, asked by another user, for future answers and recieve a notification?

Found came in to ask a question today and saw someone else had just asked pretty much exactly my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this faqs entry on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), you should be able to track a question by just setting it as a favorite (remove the favorite when you are done).
From what I remember, I was noticed when someone posted in a favorite question, even if I didn't leave any comment/answer. There may be a delay in the notify though.

EDIT:
Just to be clear, as Kit noticed in his comment, to set a question as a favorite, just click the round icon with a star under the voting commands.

Comment: +1 Just click the star next to the question and you'll see updates on the Favorites section in your profile.

Comment: Ops, added the link to the faqs and forgot to add the actual procedure for setting a favorite. Thanks for the head up Kit.

Comment: Cheers! Appreciate the help :)